# Do not assign a drive letter or drive path

Tags: hard-drive

I do not understand the function of "Do not assign a drive letter or drive path"
[image: Windows Drive Manager]

In which case is it usefull?
In which cases shouldn't it be used?

Is it good for a drive, where I only want to copy data to and from in Explorer?

Comment: Unclear : What are you doing? Some screenshots will help.

Comment: @harrymc I've added an screenshot. I added an new external harddrive to my computer, which I will remove and add from time to time

Answer (score 3):

It means that it will not give it a drive letter. It will format the drive but it will not appear with a drive letter in Explorer.

If you want to copy files to the drive using Explorer then you will need to assign a letter to it. That you don't intend to use other programs to access it is irrelevant.

---

Whats the use of this function then?

You might want to assign a letter later, or intend to format the drive before moving the disk to another machine without using it on the current machine. It's just telling Windows that you don't want it visible yet for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you. Whats the use of this function then? When I can't use the drive at all, I can simply leave it "Unallocated"

Comment: You might want to assign a letter later, or intend to format the drive before moving the disk to another machine without using it on the current machine. It's just telling Windows that you don't want it visible *yet* for whatever reason.